# Checking to see if two values are the same in an array. Python

Tags: python, arrays

This is my code

```
a = [1, "A", 2, "B", 1, "C"]
empty = []
if a[0] == a[2]:
    empty.append(a[1])
    empty.append(a[3])
elif a[0] == a[4]:
    empty.append(a[1])
    empty.append(a[5])
elif a[2] == a[4]:
    empty.append(a[3])
    empty.append(a[5])
```

I am looking for a more efficient way to carry out this process. If two elements[integers] are the same within that array, I want it to append the array[index+1] into "empty". It will have 2 Letters after if there are 2 same values in the array. 
In this example it would be ["A","C"] as they both have 1s. I would prefer finding the index position of where the duplicated items are.

Comment: What do you mean with "*It did not let me post due to "indentation errors".*"? As far as I know SO never does any indentation testing (and there are a lot of users that post completely unindented code, unfortunately).

Comment: Don't expect someone else to transcribe your code from a screenshot in order to fix your question. *You* have the code: paste it into your question.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem View the code in image. I posted the exact same thing and kept getting thrown a red error

Comment: @khelwood I would've if it had worked!, its not letting me post

Comment: I have added the code from the image. please accept the edit

Comment: Then read https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @DanielGee Thanks a lot

Comment: For future reference, when you paste code, you need to put 4 spaces in front of every line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to only find one match

```
a = [1, "A", 2, "B", 1, "C"]
empty = []
match = False

for i in range(0, len(a), 2):
    for j in range(i + 2, len(a) - 1, 2):
        if a[i] == a[j]:
            empty.append(a[i])
            empty.append(a[j])
            match = True
            break
    if match:
        break
```

and if you want all matches

```
a = [1, "A", 2, "B", 1, "C"]
empty = []

for i in range(0, len(a), 2):
    for j in range(i + 2, len(a) - 1, 2):
        if a[i] == a[j]:
            empty.append(a[i])
            empty.append(a[j])
```

if you want the indexes instead of the items change

```
empty.append(a[i])
empty.append(a[j])
```

to

```
empty.append(i)
empty.append(j)
```

**Edit**

As @Aaron pointed out, the code with the match variable can be written using the `else` clause of the `for` loop.

```
a = [1, "A", 2, "B", 1, "C"]
empty = []

for i in range(0, len(a), 2):
    for j in range(i + 2, len(a) - 1, 2):
        if a[i] == a[j]:
            empty.append(a[i])
            empty.append(a[j])
            break
    else:
        continue
    break
```

Comment: Could you find the indexes of where the same numbers are in the array, so in a = [1, "A", 2, "B", 1, "C"], it would be index, [0] and index [4]

Comment: @off-white check my answer now

Comment: to eliminate an extraneous variable `match` in your first example you could use `else: continue \n break` after your inner loop.

Comment: @Aaron didn't think of that. Ill add it to my answer

Comment: `for: else:` is something many people often forget about, and it's super helpful sometimes

Comment: you can delete do `a.pop(j)` twice, then `a.pop(i)`, as j will always be bigger than i, and when you delete an item all the others will slide down

Answer (score 1):

Try this For check duplicates

```
>>> def checkDuplicate(List):
    duplicate={}
    for i in List:
            ## checking whether the item is already present in dictionary or not
            ## increasing count if present
            ## initializing count to 1 if not present

        duplicate[i]=duplicate.get(i,0)+1

    return [k for k,v in duplicate.items() if v>1]

>>> checkDuplicate([1,2,3,"s",1,2,3])
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.combinations` to get every unique combination of two items from a list (in this case a list of the even indices). The items will be yielded in lexicographic order of the input, so if the input is sorted, the output will be as well.

```
from itertools import combinations
a = []
empty = [1, "A", 2, "B", 1, "C"]
for x,y in combinations(range(0,len(a),2),2): #take combinations in sets of 2 from the even indices
    if a[x] == a[y]:
        empty += (a[x+1], a[y+1]) #this could fail if you have an odd number of items in the list a
```

If you want to stop after matching a single pair, simply add `break` after you append items to `empty` in the "if" statement.

Answer (score 0):

This function to check the first duplicate value found and return true or false with value of what duplicate value founded

```
def is_there_two_same_value_in_arr(grouparr):
 copy_arr = copy.deepcopy(grouparr)  # Save copy of array to use the copy
 for cc in range(0,len(grouparr)-1):
    valcheck = copy_arr.pop(0)
    if(valcheck in copy_arr):
        return [True,valcheck]
    
 return [False,-1]  
a = [1, "A", 2, "B", 1, "C"]
print(is_there_two_same_value_in_arr(a))
```